# Issue with @html.password

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, popup

I'm using `@Html.Password("Password", ViewData["password"])` for displaying password in popup, the password is being displayed and I should be able to edit and update it. After editing  it, when I click save button password is not being updated.

`ModelState.IsValid` is giving `false` and the method is being skipped.

Comment: You should check the errors that the ModelState gives. You will find your answer there.

Comment: the model is not able to read the values properly from the textbox where i declared @html.password..

Comment: If the value is not binded to the model check whether the property name matches the field name i.e. *password*

Answer (score 1):

From [Password Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460493%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) signature

```
public static string Password(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name
)
```

second argument is

```
The name of the form field and the ViewDataDictionary key that is used to look up the value.
```

So it is practically wrong to pass `ViewData["password"]` as second argument.

MVC will automatically look for value into `ViewData`, so you could just write

```
@Html.Password("Password")
```

Or do everything *correct way* and use strongly typed view models

Comment: +1 for emphasizing the importance of strongly-typed view models.

Comment: where should i pass the first argument, model?also in string name, what is name??

Comment: @beingfab as i mentioned, writing `@Html.Password("Password")` is enough.